# Uploadify doesn't work in forefox and safari

Tags: jquery, uploadify

All good in chrome, ie and opera. But in FF and Safari this plugin don't work(
Even the link does not turn into a button.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        acync: true,
        folder: 'Uploads/',
        swf: '/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        uploader: '@Url.Action("UploadFotos", "Fotos", new { id = ViewData.Model.Id})',
        fileExt: "*.jpg,*jpeg",
        fileSizeLimit: '2MB',
        onUploadSuccess: function (file, data, response) {
            var d = JSON.parse(data);
            if (d.success == false) {
                alert("У вас не хватает прав для этого действия");
            } else {
            $("#fotos-container").append("<div class='foto' id='" + d.id + "'></div>");
            $("div#" + d.id).append("<img src='/uploads/thumbs/" + d.name + "' />");
            $("div#" + d.id).append("<input type='checkbox' onclick='ToogleMain(" + d.id + ")'/> Главное фото <br />");
            $("div#" + d.id).append("<a href='#' onclick='deletefoto(this" + d.id + ")'> Удалить </a>");
        }

        }
    });
});
```

UPD:

**Problem is solved! It was necessary to install flash player for browsers.**

Comment: Have you looked at the console in firebug for errors?

Comment: From my experience, debugging Uploadify has always been a pain. Please check your javascript console output in case there are errors. Also, if possible, check the called server-side script's output.

Comment: Yes. And i have warnings in css, but in js files there were no errors.